# How do you send a tweet?

Tags: twitter

My granddaughter set me up with a Twitter account.  I know how to read tweets from people I follow.  I do not know how to reply to people I dont follow but would like to comment on a # comment.

I tried last night from my ipad when I saw a news programme I wanted to comment on but did not know how.

Answer (score 1):

> how to reply to people I dont follow

In the same way you reply to someone you do follow. Find the tweet you want to reply to and hit the [Reply] link below.

To arbitrarily *mention* someone in a tweet (ie. send them a public message, without replying to a specific tweet) then use the at-sign `@` followed by the recipients twitter ID.

```
@newsprogramme I strongly disagree with your report on the abc!
```

@replies and @mentions are really the same thing, except @replies record the conversation thread.